# TableRow height wrap_content doesn't work

Tags: android-button, android-tablelayout

I have a TableLayout with several TableRows defined in xml. All the rows has weight of 1, but the first row has weight of 0 and the height defined as "wrap_content" as following:

```
<TableRow 
        android:layout_weight="0" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/row">
      <Button
         android:id="@+id/tbl_txt1"
         android:layout_width="0dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Small"
         android:gravity="center"/>

      <Button
         android:id="@+id/tbl_txt2"
         android:layout_width="0dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Small"
         android:gravity="center"/>
</TableRow>
```

the problem is that in devices with android 2.3 it's work fine (wrapping the content of the button) but in devices with android 4 (ics) it doesn't wrapping anything (has fix height).
i tried fill_parent and the result is the same.